# how to make element center in customized react-slick?

Tags: reactjs, swipe, swiper.js, react-slick

[image: Demo]

I try to make this active dot center of widows. but i can't do that. any one help me for that?

i have added code sandbox link here: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ccmt-slider-lr8srh?file=/src/App.js)